# Chat Client Server C++

Tags: c++

I decided to make an application that adds to chat only people that are in the list. The server and the client side there is a structure User.I need your help because after sent data
from client to server I haven't it on the server side and it doesn't work... It is no cool.

server:

```
    sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    listen(sock,5);
    accept(dlg->sock,(sockaddr*)&(dlg->serv),&(dlg->addlen));
    AfxBeginThread(thread,0);
    memset(dlg->logined.login,NULL,sizeof(dlg->logined.login));
    memset(dlg->logined.pass,NULL,sizeof(dlg->logined.pass));
    recv(dlg->sock, dlg->logined.login, sizeof(dlg->logined.login),0);
    dlg->m_list.InsertItem(dlg->count++,dlg->logined.login);
    ...
```

and client:

```
UINT thread(LPVOID v)
{
    char buff[100]
    CSize size;
    size.cx=0;
    size.cy=30;
    int s=1,addcount=0;

CClisockDlg *dlg=(CClisockDlg*) AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd();

dlg->m_connect.EnableWindow(FALSE);
dlg->m_disconnect.EnableWindow(TRUE);
while(connect(dlg->clisock,(sockaddr*)&(dlg->cli),sizeof(dlg->cli)) && dlg->ee!=0)
{
    dlg->m_edit.SetWindowText("Connection...wait");
    for (int i=0;i<=65000;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<=200;j++);
    if (addcount==25)
        addcount=0;
    dlg->cli.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(dlg->user.ip);
}
    if (dlg->ee==1)
    dlg->m_list.InsertItem(dlg->count++,"Connected");   
    dlg->SetForegroundWindow();
while((s=recv(dlg->clisock,buff,100,0))!=SOCKET_ERROR && dlg->ee!=0)
{

    dlg->SetForegroundWindow();
    if (s!=SOCKET_ERROR && dlg->ee!=0)
    dlg->m_list.InsertItem(dlg->count++,buff);
    dlg->m_list.Scroll(size);
}
send(dlg->clisock,"Disconnected",100,0);
dlg->m_connect.EnableWindow(TRUE);
dlg->m_disconnect.EnableWindow(FALSE);
closesocket(dlg->clisock);
AfxEndThread(0);
return 0;
}


void CClisockDlg::OnButton2() //  Button  m_connect       
{

    m_edit2.GetWindowText(user.ip,sizeof(user.ip));
    m_edit3.GetWindowText(user.login,sizeof(user.login));
    m_edit4.GetWindowText(user.pass,sizeof(user.pass));
    cli.sin_family=AF_INET;
    cli.sin_port=htons(5000);
    cli.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(user.ip);
    clisock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    send(clisock,user.login,sizeof(user.login),0);
    send(clisock, user.pass, sizeof(user.pass), 0);
    AfxBeginThread(thread,0);
}
```

How to make the data structures have been adopted on the server? Now connection is established and datas login and password is lost.

Comment: You should specify your particular problems, expected inputs and outputs. _'doesn't work...it is no cool'_ is a bit spare info, isn't it??

Comment: Show what the data types are for your text buffers.

Comment: I have a form of the three fields - IP, Login, Password. After the fields have been filled you pressed the only button How do I make add client to chat in one click? To  ScottMcP-MVP Struct User: {char ip[30];char login[16]; char password[16]}

Answer (score 3):

You can do what I did I guess. Create a class for socket communication first and make sure it works..

I have some working code I wrote below a while ago. You can see how it is done below.. I also uploaded the source for both the server and the client (compile it using Codeblocks and gcc/g++ 4.8.1): http://www.mediafire.com/download/6j84bedkp3s3sq5/Socket+Chat.zip

Socket.hpp:

```
#ifndef SOCKETS_HPP_INCLUDED
#define SOCKETS_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#define WM_SOCKET 0x10000

class Socket
{
    private:
        SOCKET socket;
        std::uint32_t Port;
        std::string Address;
        HWND WindowHandle;
        bool Listen, Initialized, Asynchronous;

    public:
        Socket(){};
        Socket(std::uint32_t Port, std::string Address, bool Listen = false, HWND WindowHandle = nullptr, bool Asynchronous = false);
        ~Socket();
        int Recv(void* Buffer, std::uint32_t BufferLength);
        int Recv(SOCKET S, void* Buffer, std::uint32_t BufferLength);
        int Send(void* Buffer, std::size_t BufferSize);
        int Send(SOCKET S, void* Buffer, std::size_t BufferSize);

        void Connect(std::uint32_t Port, std::string Address, bool Listen, HWND WindowHandle, bool Asynchronous);
        SOCKET Accept(sockaddr* ClientInfo, int* ClientInfoSize);
        SOCKET GetSocket() const;
        void Close();
};

#endif // SOCKETS_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Socket.cpp:

```
#include "Sockets.hpp"

std::string ErrorMessage(std::uint32_t Error, bool Throw = true)
{
    LPTSTR lpMsgBuf = nullptr;
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, nullptr, Error, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&lpMsgBuf), 0, nullptr);
    if (Throw)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(lpMsgBuf);
    }
    return lpMsgBuf;
}

Socket::~Socket()
{
    Close();
}

void Socket::Close()
{
    if (socket)
    {
        shutdown(socket, SD_BOTH);
        closesocket(socket);
        socket = 0;
    }

    if (Initialized)
    {
        WSACleanup();
    }
}

SOCKET Socket::GetSocket() const {return this->socket;}

Socket::Socket(std::uint32_t Port, std::string Address, bool Listen, HWND WindowHandle, bool Asynchronous) : socket(0)
{
    Connect(Port, Address, Listen, WindowHandle, Asynchronous);
}

void Socket::Connect(std::uint32_t Port, std::string Address, bool Listen, HWND WindowHandle, bool Asynchronous)
{
    if (!socket)
    {
        this->Port = Port;
        this->Address = Address;
        this->Listen = Listen;
        this->WindowHandle = WindowHandle;
        this->Asynchronous = Asynchronous;
        this->Initialized = true;

        WSADATA wsaData;
        struct sockaddr_in* sockaddr_ipv4;

        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Error: " + ErrorMessage(WSAGetLastError()));
        }

        if ((this->socket = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            this->Close();
            throw std::runtime_error("Error: " + ErrorMessage(WSAGetLastError()));
        }

        if (Address != "INADDR_ANY")
        {
            struct addrinfo *result = nullptr;
            getaddrinfo(Address.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, &result);
            struct addrinfo* it;
            for (it = result; it != nullptr; it = it->ai_next)
            {
                sockaddr_ipv4 = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(it->ai_addr);
                Address = inet_ntoa(sockaddr_ipv4->sin_addr);
                if (Address != "0.0.0.0") break;
            }
            freeaddrinfo(result);
        }

        SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
        memset(&SockAddr, 0, sizeof(SockAddr));
        SockAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
        SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = (Address == "INADDR_ANY" ? htonl(INADDR_ANY) : inet_addr(Address.c_str()));

        if (Listen && (bind(this->socket, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR))
        {
            this->Close();
            std::string Error = ErrorMessage(WSAGetLastError());
            throw std::runtime_error("Error: " + ErrorMessage(WSAGetLastError()));
        }

        if (Asynchronous && WindowHandle)
        {
            if(WSAAsyncSelect(socket, WindowHandle, WM_SOCKET, FD_READ | FD_WRITE | FD_CONNECT | FD_CLOSE | FD_ACCEPT) != 0)
            {
                this->Close();
                throw std::runtime_error("Error: " + ErrorMessage(WSAGetLastError()));
            }
        }

        if (Listen && (listen(this->socket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR))
        {
            this->Close();
            throw std::runtime_error("Error: " + ErrorMessage(WSAGetLastError()));
        }

        if(!Listen && (connect(this->socket, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR))
        {
            if(Asynchronous && WindowHandle && (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK))
            {
                this->Close();
                throw std::runtime_error("Error: " + ErrorMessage(WSAGetLastError()));
            }
        }
    }
}

SOCKET Socket::Accept(sockaddr* ClientInfo, int* ClientInfoSize)
{
    static int Size = sizeof(sockaddr);
    return accept(this->socket, ClientInfo, (ClientInfo && ClientInfoSize ? ClientInfoSize : &Size));
}
int Socket::Recv(void* Buffer, std::uint32_t BufferLength)
{
    return recv(this->socket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(Buffer), BufferLength, 0);
}

int Socket::Recv(SOCKET S, void* Buffer, std::uint32_t BufferLength)
{
    return recv(S, reinterpret_cast<char*>(Buffer), BufferLength, 0);
}

int Socket::Send(void* Buffer, std::size_t BufferSize)
{
    return send(this->socket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(Buffer), BufferSize, 0);
}

int Socket::Send(SOCKET S, void* Buffer, std::size_t BufferSize)
{
    return send(S, reinterpret_cast<char*>(Buffer), BufferSize, 0);
}
```

The above is just a wrapper around a socket that makes thing very easy to use.

Now for the client and server windows, I created another wrapper around the WinAPI functions to make creating of windows easy!

Window.hpp:

```
#ifndef WINDOW_HPP_INCLUDED
#define WINDOW_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

class Window
{
    private:
        HWND WindowHandle;
        static LRESULT __stdcall WindowProcedure(HWND Hwnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    public:
        void Create(std::string ClassName, std::string Title, int Width = CW_USEDEFAULT, int Height = CW_USEDEFAULT, WNDPROC WindowProcedure = nullptr, WNDCLASSEX WndClass = {0});
        HWND GetWindowHandle();
};

#endif // WINDOW_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Window.cpp:

```
#include "Window.hpp"

LRESULT __stdcall Window::WindowProcedure(HWND Hwnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {    
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(Hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
};

void Window::Create(std::string ClassName, std::string Title, int Width, int Height, WNDPROC WindowProcedure, WNDCLASSEX WndClass)
{
    if (WindowProcedure == nullptr)
    {
        WindowProcedure = Window::WindowProcedure;
    }

    if (WndClass.cbSize == 0)
    {
        WndClass =
        {
            sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_DBLCLKS, WindowProcedure,
            0, 0, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION),
            LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW), HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW),
            nullptr, ClassName.c_str(), LoadIcon (nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION)
        };
    }

    if(RegisterClassEx(&WndClass))
    {
        this->WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, ClassName.c_str(), Title.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, Width, Height, nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), nullptr);
        if(WindowHandle)
        {
            MSG msg = {nullptr};
            ShowWindow(WindowHandle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
            while(GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Protocol.hpp:

```
    #include "Sockets.hpp"
    #include <iostream>
/**
        Packet Protocol Definition. Can probably make this into an Enum later when it gets more complex.
        This protocol determines how a packet is read. Is it a packet for the server? The client? What type? etc..
    **/
    const int PACKET_PROTOCOL_SERVER_ID = -3; //A Server packet telling all clients a global message or Sends clients a unique ID upon connect.
    const int PACKET_PROTOCOL_UPDATE_ID = -2; //Sends a packet to the server telling it we want to update other clients with our new info.
    const int PACKET_PROTOCOL_CLIENT_DISC = -1; //A client has disconnected, update our contacts list.
    const int PACKET_PROTOCOL_CLIENT_CONN = 0; //A client has connected, update our contacts list.

    //const int PACKET_PROTOCOL_              //Add other protocols such as admin-login, authenticate, etc..
                                              //If you add more, don't forget to update the Packet struct.


    /**
        A structure that represents a packet to be sent over a network/socket.
    **/
    struct Packet
    {
        std::int32_t ID;
        std::int32_t To;
        std::int32_t From;

        std::string Name;
        std::string Message;
    };

    template <typename T>
    T ReadPointer(char*& Pointer)
    {
        T Result = *(reinterpret_cast<T*>(Pointer));
        Pointer += sizeof(T);
        return Result;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void WritePointer(char*& Pointer, const T& Value)
    {
        *(reinterpret_cast<T*>(Pointer)) = Value;
        Pointer += sizeof(T);
    }

    /**
        Serializes a packet into a buffer of unsigned-chars.. aka bytes. Then sends it through the socket.
    **/
    bool WritePacket(SOCKET s, Packet &packet)
    {
        if (s)
        {
            std::vector<char> Buffer((sizeof(int32_t) * 3) + sizeof(packet.Name.size()) + packet.Name.size() + sizeof(packet.Message.size()) + packet.Message.size(), 0);
            char* Ptr = Buffer.data();

            WritePointer(Ptr, packet.ID);
            WritePointer(Ptr, packet.To);
            WritePointer(Ptr, packet.From);
            WritePointer(Ptr, packet.Name.size());

            for (auto it = packet.Name.begin(); it != packet.Name.end(); ++it)
                WritePointer(Ptr, *it);

            WritePointer(Ptr, packet.Message.size());
            for (auto it = packet.Message.begin(); it != packet.Message.end(); ++it)
                WritePointer(Ptr, *it);

            send(s, Buffer.data(), Buffer.size(), 0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
        Deserializes a buffer of unsigned-chars.. aka bytes back into a packet.
    **/
    bool ReadPacket(SOCKET s, Packet &packet)
    {
        if (s)
        {
            packet.Name.clear();
            recv(s, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&packet.ID), sizeof(packet.ID), 0);
            recv(s, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&packet.To), sizeof(packet.To), 0);
            recv(s, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&packet.From), sizeof(packet.From), 0);

            decltype(packet.Name.size()) Size = 0;
            recv(s, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Size), sizeof(Size), 0);

            std::vector<char> Buffer(Size, 0);
            recv(s, Buffer.data(), Buffer.size(), 0);
            packet.Name.append(Buffer.begin(), Buffer.end());
            Buffer.clear();

            Size = 0;
            recv(s, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Size), sizeof(Size), 0);

            recv(s, Buffer.data(), Buffer.size(), 0);
            packet.Message.append(Buffer.begin(), Buffer.end());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

All of the above headers and source files will be used in BOTH the client and server. The protocol is the link between the client and server. It described the packet and how to read/write it. It is how the server and client will communicate back and forth!

---

For the **Server** I did:

**On Start:**
As you can see above, the server must be running first. It will listen on the localhost and it will be listening on port 27015.

**On Client Connect:**
Upon a client connecting, the client is issued a unique ID and added to a list on the server. You can see this happening in FD_ACCEPT.

**On Message Received:**
Next, if a client sends a message, FD_READ is triggered and the server begins to read the packet sent by the client. If it is an update packet, the packet is sent to ALL other clients on the server so that the other clients can update their information about the client who sent the packet. We also update the client's info stored on the server.
If it is a server packet, we consume it and send it back to the client.

**On Client Disconnect:**
Upon disconnect, aka FD_CLOSE, you can see that the server sends a disconnect packet to all other client notifying them that "some client" has disconnected. Then it removes the client from the list and closes the client's socket.

Server's main.cpp:

```
#include "Sockets.hpp"
#include "Window.hpp"
#include "Protocol.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <map>


/**
    Packet Protocol Definition. Can probably make this into an Enum later when it gets more complex.
    This protocol determines how a packet is read. Is it a packet for the server? The client? What type? etc..
**/
Socket* sock = nullptr;
bool SocketConnected = false;

/**
    Stores information about each client that connects.
**/
std::vector<std::tuple<int, SOCKET, Packet>> Clients;

auto FindClient(int ID) -> decltype(Clients.begin())
{
    for (auto it = Clients.begin(); it != Clients.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (std::get<0>(*it) == ID)
            return it;
    }
    return Clients.end();
}

auto FindClient(SOCKET socket) -> decltype(Clients.begin())
{
    for (auto it = Clients.begin(); it != Clients.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (std::get<1>(*it) == socket)
            return it;
    }
    return Clients.end();
}

void SendAll(Packet &packet)
{
    for (auto it = Clients.begin(); it != Clients.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (std::get<0>(*it) != packet.From)
        {
            packet.To = std::get<0>(*it);
            WritePacket(std::get<1>(*it), packet);
        }
    }
}

LRESULT __stdcall WindowProcedure(HWND Hwnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            sock = new Socket(27015, "INADDR_ANY", true, Hwnd, true);
        }
        break;

        case WM_SOCKET:  /** We received a socket event **/
        {
            switch(WSAGETSELECTEVENT(lParam))
            {
                case FD_WRITE:
                {
                    SocketConnected = true;
                }
                break;

                case FD_READ: /** We have received a packet from the client. Read the ID and interpret the packet information. **/
                {
                    Packet P;
                    ReadPacket(reinterpret_cast<SOCKET>(wParam), P);

                    if (P.ID == PACKET_PROTOCOL_UPDATE_ID)
                    {
                        auto it = FindClient(P.From);
                        if (it != Clients.end())
                        {
                            Packet* Client = &std::get<2>(*it);
                            Client->Name = P.Name;

                            for (auto it = Clients.begin(); it != Clients.end(); ++it)
                            {
                                P.ID = PACKET_PROTOCOL_UPDATE_ID;
                                P.From = std::get<0>(*it);
                                SendAll(P);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (P.ID == PACKET_PROTOCOL_SERVER_ID)
                    {
                        auto it = FindClient(P.To);
                        if (it != Clients.end())
                        {
                            WritePacket(std::get<1>(*it), P);
                        }
                    }

                    SocketConnected = true;
                }
                break;

                case FD_ACCEPT: //A client wants to connect. We accept them and store them in our list.
                {
                    int ClientID = 1;
                    while(FindClient(ClientID) != Clients.end())
                    {
                        ++ClientID;
                    }

                    Packet Client;
                    sockaddr_in ClientAddressInfo = {0};
                    Clients.push_back(std::make_tuple(ClientID, sock->Accept(reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&ClientAddressInfo), nullptr), Client));

                    Packet PacketInfo;
                    PacketInfo.ID = PACKET_PROTOCOL_SERVER_ID;
                    PacketInfo.To = ClientID;
                    SocketConnected = true;
                    WritePacket(std::get<1>(Clients.back()), PacketInfo);
                }
                break;

                case FD_CLOSE: //A client has disconnected. Notify all other clients and remove the client from our list.
                {
                    auto it = FindClient(reinterpret_cast<SOCKET>(wParam));
                    if (it != Clients.end())
                    {
                        Packet PacketInfo;
                        PacketInfo.ID = PACKET_PROTOCOL_CLIENT_DISC;
                        PacketInfo.From = std::get<0>(*it);
                        SendAll(PacketInfo);
                        Clients.erase(it);
                    }
                }
                break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            sock->Close();
            delete sock;
            WSACleanup();
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        return 0;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(Hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Window().Create("Server", "Server", 200, 100, WindowProcedure, {0});
}
```

---

For the **Client** I did:

**On Start:**
When the window is created, it attempts to connect to the server.

**On Connect:**
Upon connection to the server, FD_WRITE message is received. In the FD_WRITE switch case, we simply construct a basic packet and send it to the server letting them know our name, our information, etc.. The server will receive an UPDATE packet and update our information as well as notify all other clients that we exist.

**On Receive:**
Upon receiving a message, FD_READ is triggered. We need to read the packet we received from the server and interpret it how we wish. Currently, the first packet received from the server is our unique ID which was issued to us and a list of all contacts connected.

Also, if the packet is NOT a server packet, we need to simply read the packet and append the text to the receive box! This will display all messages received by other contacts or clients on the server.

**On Disconnect:**
Upon disconnect message being received (FD_CLOSE) I decided to close the socket instead of retrying to connect. It is as simple as that. You can do `delete sock; sock = new....` to reconnect if you wish.

Client's main.cpp:

```
#include "Sockets.hpp"
#include "Window.hpp"
#include "Protocol.hpp"
#include <vector>

/**
    Global variables:
        Socket
        ClientID
        Handles for controls
        IDs for controls
**/

int ClientID = -1;
int ReceiverID = -1;
std::string ClientName = "Client";
Socket* sock = nullptr;
bool SocketConnected = false;
HWND SendBox, ReceiveBox, SendButton;
enum {SENDBOX_ID, RECEIVEBOX_ID, SENDBUTTON_ID};


LRESULT __stdcall WindowProcedure(HWND Hwnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            ReceiveBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, "Edit", nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_READONLY, 10, 10, 465, 275, Hwnd, (HMENU)RECEIVEBOX_ID, nullptr, nullptr);
            SendBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, "Edit", nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 10, 315, 465, 110, Hwnd, (HMENU)SENDBOX_ID, nullptr, nullptr);
            SendButton = CreateWindowEx(0, "Button", "Send", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 385, 430, 90, 25, Hwnd, (HMENU)SENDBUTTON_ID, nullptr, nullptr);

            sock = new Socket(27015, "localhost", false, Hwnd, true);
        }
        break;

        case WM_COMMAND: /** We received an event from a button/control **/
        {
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case SENDBUTTON_ID: //The send button was pressed so we want to construct a packet from the sendbox's contents and send it to the server.
                {
                    Packet P;
                    std::vector<std::uint8_t> Buffer(GetWindowTextLength(SendBox) + 1);
                    GetWindowText(SendBox, reinterpret_cast<char*>(Buffer.data()), Buffer.size());
                    P.Message.append(Buffer.begin(), Buffer.end());

                    if (!P.Message.empty())
                    {
                        P.ID = ReceiverID;  //The packet is NOT meant for the server. It is meant for the client.
                        P.To = ReceiverID;  //We will be sending the packet to some other client.
                        P.From = ClientID;  //The packet is from this client.
                        P.Name = ClientName; //Our name..
                        WritePacket(sock->GetSocket(), P);
                    }
                }
                break;

                case RECEIVEBOX_ID:
                {
                    if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_SETFOCUS)
                    {
                        HideCaret(ReceiveBox);
                    }
                    else if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_KILLFOCUS)
                    {
                        ShowCaret(ReceiveBox);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        break;

        case WM_SOCKET:  /** We received a socket event **/
        {
            switch(WSAGETSELECTEVENT(lParam))
            {
                case FD_WRITE:   /** We connected to the server successfully so we need to send an initialization packet. **/
                {
                    SocketConnected = true;

                    Packet P;
                    P.ID = PACKET_PROTOCOL_UPDATE_ID;
                    P.To = PACKET_PROTOCOL_SERVER_ID;
                    P.From = -1;      /** The server will send us a unique Identifier. **/
                    P.Name = "ICantChooseUsernames";
                    P.Message = "Hello";
                    WritePacket(sock->GetSocket(), P);
                }
                break;

                case FD_READ: /** We have received a packet from the server. Read the ID and interpret the packet information. **/
                {
                    Packet P;
                    ReadPacket(sock->GetSocket(), P);

                    if (P.ID == PACKET_PROTOCOL_SERVER_ID) //If the packet is a server packet, then it is sending us our Unique client ID.
                    {
                        ClientID = P.To;
                        SetWindowText(Hwnd, (ClientName + ": " + std::to_string(P.ID)).c_str()); //Set the window title to "OurName: " + OurID.
                    }
                    else if (P.ID == PACKET_PROTOCOL_CLIENT_DISC)
                    {
                        //Delete the specified contact from our contacts list..
                    }
                    else if (P.ID == PACKET_PROTOCOL_CLIENT_CONN)
                    {
                        //Add the client to the contacts list..
                    }
                    else //Else print the packet's message in the received box..
                    {
                        std::string Sender = P.Name;
                        std::string Message = P.Message;
                        int ReceiveBoxLength = GetWindowTextLength(ReceiveBox);
                        Message = ReceiveBoxLength == 0 ? Sender + ": " + Message : "\r\n\r\n" + Sender + ": " + Message;
                        SendMessage(ReceiveBox, EM_SETSEL, -1, -1);
                        SendMessage(ReceiveBox, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(Message.c_str()));
                    }
                }
                break;

                case FD_CLOSE:
                {
                    sock->Close();
                }
                break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            sock->Close();
            delete sock;
            WSACleanup();
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        return 0;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(Hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Window().Create("Client", "Client", 500, 500, WindowProcedure, {0});
}
```

Comment: I don't understand here: Server->Accepts Client->Read PacketID. After connection true, I can't to read any message from OnButton2.Server->Accepts Client workes, no: ->Read PacketID.

Comment: How do I can to send from client data for accept and data for ID before connection established?

Comment: I edited my answer. Hopefully you understand that. I'm not so sure I can simplify it any more than that. I tried adding more comments by an answer is limited to 30000 characters at most.

Comment: I will make as: [link](http://zalivalka.ru/66829)                 There are three or more fields on client side not filled so connection is not established. You fill all, click on, and connect... Server has file.dat where were written the names and passwords all clients. Before connection client must to fill  fields and server makes verification and if it didn't find something login or password - connection closes. I have code but it doesn't work. I think maybe you will prompt me... I began above.

Comment: to:CantChooseUsernames   Window (). Create ("Server", "Server", 200, 100, WindowProcedure, {0})   with the following parameters window didn't create.

Comment: It does create a window. {0} makes it use the default wndclass. I'm not sure about Visual Studio but it certainly creates one in gcc.

Comment: to:CantChooseUsernames  So I remade your code for VC but only server side. I think {0}  WNDCLASSEX WndClass  isn't  default.  VC don't create win 32, only console. I think what I will do in this situation. You need use namespace std.  This will help to avoid copying std:: function() at every turn.